# Update required when turn on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, software-update, startup

I recently install Yosemite, I then found that every time I turn my computer off and turn it back on, it would ask for my password for an update (Update Required) it would then go through an update with a progression bar and then boot as normal. I have been on the App Store and checked if I require any updates for anything and it just says I am up too date. Any suggestions on how to make this stop or what it is actually doing would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the Yosemite, but on Mavericks you can turn off the Auto Updates in System Preferences.

Open App Store in syst pref and disable the automatically check for update.

After restart you can enable it again to see if it is working now as it should.

If not use Disk Utility and repair the disk permissions.